# grails/hibernate: get org.hibernate.StaleStateException in a Job

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have an exception that occured not systematically.
I tried to fix the issue by flushing and cleaning the session in each iteration but without success.

```
[quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - Exception executing batch: org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
        at bosmonitor.MyJob$_execute_closure1.doCall(MyJob.groovy:27)
        at bosmonitor.MyJob.execute(MyJob.groovy:25)
        at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:102)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

**Class**

```
class Product {
    int duration = 0
    int timer = 0
    // ...  

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }   
}
```

Poste updated by adding the service that call the job.

**MyService**

```
def ProductInstance = Product.get(1)

MyJob.schedule(1000L,0)
MyJob.triggerNow([ProductInstance:ProductInstance])
```

**Job**

```
class MyJob {
    def sessionFactory

    static triggers = {}

    def execute(context) {  
        def ProductInstance = context.mergedJobDataMap.get('ProductInstance')

        if (ProductInstance) {          
            // loop every second
            while (ProductInstance.timer < ProductInstance.duration) {  
                def millis = System.currentTimeMillis()     

                Product.withTransaction {               
                    ProductInstance.timer = ++ProductInstance.timer     
                    ProductInstance.merge(flush: true)
                    def hibSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    hibSession.flush()
                    hibSession.clear()
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000 - millis % 1000)
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: How about injecting a service into your job then getting a @Transactional service to do the job for you ? Also what is  context.mergedJobDataMap.get('ProductInstance') can you do a println "-- productInstance is ${ProductInstance.getClass()}" after def productInstance and tell everyone what that is too

Comment: I replaced `withSession` by `withTransaction`, but the exception still occured.

Comment: you didn't answer my point raised above about the getClass. What happens if you put that code into a service and then call it via  a controller a a test - does it work outside of quartz schedule all ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the withSession stuff and put the transactional code in a service?!

also, enabling failOnError when saving sometimes helps getting to the root error...